# What does tuple index out of range mean?

Tags: python, printing, format

Can anybody shed some light on why:

```
print('{0} complete (down: {1} kb/s up: {2} kb/s {3} peers: {4} {5}'.format('state.progress * 100', 'state.download_rate / 1000', 'state.upload_rate / 1000', 'state.num_peers', 'state_str[state.state]'))
```

Results in a tuple index out of range?

Comment: You don't have an index 5 element.

Comment: you have called {5} where as you have only given 5 elements. So tuple index out of range

Comment: In possibly more colloquial words, you don't have an element _with index 5_. Technically index 4 is the "fifth" element, unless you count the "zeroth" element.

Comment: Given that you've correctly used `0` for the first element, could you shed some light on why you expected anything else?

Comment: Also, note that doing '{0}'.format('state.progress * 100') is going to return 'state.progress * 100' [i.e. the literal string] and note the value state.progress * 100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a "fifth" (or rather, index 5) element because the first element has index 0.

Therefore you have to have 6 elements to use index 5.

```
print('{0} complete (down: {1} kb/s up: {2} kb/s {3} peers: {4} {5}'.format('state.progress * 100', 'state.download_rate / 1000', 'state.upload_rate / 1000', 'state.num_peers', 'state_str[state.state]'))
```

Here, your elements are:

```
0: 'state.progress * 100'
1: 'state.download_rate / 1000'
2: 'state.upload_rate / 1000'
3: 'state.num_peers'
4: 'state_str[state.state]'
5: nil
```

Comment: I will be the greatest python programmer in the world.  Once I learn to count.

Comment: Could you shed some light on how I force print to display to two decimal points in python3?

Comment: a) That's a new question b) That can easily be found by searching